# Convert a --data-urlencode in CURL for google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a Google Apps Script that converts this call

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC82950e7259813d6695afc79412c7a06f/Messages.json'/ 
  --data-urlencode 'To=+441632960675'  \
  --data-urlencode 'MessagingServiceSid=MG9752274e9e519418a7406176694466fa'  \
  --data-urlencode 'Body=Phantom Menace was clearly the best of the prequel trilogy.'  \
  -u AC82950e7259813d6695afc79412c7a06f:auth_token
```

to be compliant in google app script using the UrlFetchApp.fetch() command.

My code looks like this

```
    function sendcopilot() {
      var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC82950e7259813d6695afc79412c7a06f/Messages.json";

      var payload = {
        "To": "+1415555555",
        "MessagingServiceSid":"sidid",
        "Body" : "Phantom Menace"

      };
   var options = {

        "method" : "post",
        "payload" : payload
      };

      options.headers = {
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("mytoken:mysecret")
      };

      UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
    }
```

The error that I keep getting seems like I am not doing the "--data-urlencode " piece but I can not work out how to do it in Google Apps Script

Comment: I thought that your script works like the curl sample. So can you show us the response message for the script?

Comment: No it keeps erroring that I am not using a valid MessagingServiceSid . I think I need to encode it somehow

Answer (score 2):

The key to this is that the context type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Here's a working example.

You have to update the credentials:

```
function sendText(link, from) {
  const TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = 'XXX';
  const TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = 'YYY';
  const link = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID + '/Messages.json';
  let formData = {
    'Body': 'See ' + link + '\n\nClick link to see detail and schedule a viewing.\n\nReply STOP to end receiving matches.',
    'From': 'xxx',
    'To': 'xxx',
    'MediaUrl': 'https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png'
  };
  var options =
  {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'payload': formData
  };
  options.headers = { "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN) };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(link, options);
}
```